# Is it possible to tag a Windows process's description via the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, windows-server-2008

imagine i want to run a program called `Foo.exe` in the Windows command line. Is there a way I can tag that process 'Description' field, when I look in the `Task Manager -> Processes` ? BTW, the exe isn't mine / i can't compile it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description field that is displayed by the task manager is read from the version resource of the executable file. So you can't change it (tag it) when you start the process. If you want to influence what appears there then you need to modify the executable which I don't believe is what you are looking to do.

Comment: So if i run multiple copies of the same .exe (eg. chrome or mozilla, etc) then i can't tag each process? Damn :(  Cheers for the clarification!

Comment: No I believe what you are looking for is not easily achievable. FWIW, if you run a single copy of chrome, it will spawn extra processes for each tab.

Comment: @Pure.Krome, FWIW, you can add the "command line" column to the task manager view. Will provide you with a little bit more information on some cases (say when trying to tell which chrome process does what).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [SetConsoleTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API.  That will let you set the title of the window containing the console.  This is the string which shows up in task manager->applications.  It doesn't help with Task Manager->processes (as David Heffernan mentioned, that comes from the version resource and is immutable), but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore. Task manager doesn't have an application tab as well, so I guess this might have been true in the past.